# IntelliJ: stop expansion to fully qualified names in JavaDoc

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I add JavaDoc documentation to some class and use `{@link SomeClass}` or `@throws SomeException` etc.. IntelliJ automatically expands these classes to their full names even if it is not required at the moment meaning:

`{@link SomeClass}` automatically becomes `{@link sometopnamespace.somecategory.somepackage.SomeClass}` which makes the documentation hard to read in comments.

Is there a setting in IntelliJ to not make it auto expand class names in JavaDoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be changed in Settings/Editor/Code style/Java/Imports by unchecking Use fully qualified names in JavaDoc.

Answer (score 2):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15**

File > Settings ... > Editor > Code Style > Java > Imports > Use fully qualified class names in JavaDoc > select "Never, use short name and add import"

[image]